# kubectl rollout status does not wait for deployment to complete and pod to run

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

We deploy new images with `kubectl` (see below) and occasionally see that `kubectly rollout status` command complete even though the new pods did not start.

As you can see below kubectl even admits and logs "0 out of 1 new replicas have been updated" and continues on regardless.

Is this a bug?

We do not have any liveness/readiness probes configures. Perhaps kubectl did not wait long enough to see if the process was healthy? Our NodeJS app crashed on line 3 (a `require()` statement very early on) and before any long-running code was run.

Attempt 1:

```bash
kubectl get deployment/documents
# Updating existing deployment documents:1.13.1.337660...
# Applying New Image Tag to Deployment...
kubectl set image deployment/documents documents=myrepo.com/documents:1.13.1.337660
deployment.apps/documents image updated
# Waiting for rollout to complete
kubectl rollout status deployment/documents
Waiting for deployment spec update to be observed...
Waiting for deployment spec update to be observed...
Waiting for deployment "documents" rollout to finish: 0 out of 1 new replicas have been updated...
Waiting for deployment "documents" rollout to finish: 1 old replicas are pending termination...
Waiting for deployment "documents" rollout to finish: 1 old replicas are pending termination...
deployment "documents" successfully rolled out
```

This attempt exits even though the new pod was faulty and did/could not start!

Attempt 2:

```bash
kubectl get deployment/documents
# Updating existing deployment documents:1.13.1.337660...
# Applying New Image Tag to Deployment...
kubectl set image deployment/documents documents=myrepo.com/documents:1.13.1.337660
# Waiting for rollout to complete
kubectl rollout status deployment/documents
Waiting for deployment "documents" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
```

This never exits - correctly because the pod cannot start!

UPDATE: I have filed a kubectl bug [#1284](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1284) about this.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in kubernetes v1.21, check your kubelet service status(check the log to make sure the kubelet did not restart and running fine all the time or in a peroid long time).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. `kubectl rollout status` will wait forever unless you pass `--timeout=X` where X is a number and unit indicating how long you want it to wait for, such as `1m`, `5m`, or `10m`.

Even so, the timeout will not rollback that faulty update, you would need to detect the failure (e.g. by using `$?`) and do a `kubectl rollout undo`

Comment: We ran the same deployment twice (see my example) the second time it correctly failed by never returning success. Yes we could add a timeout but why did the first deployment return success? We had a bad deployment we could not detect because kubectl said: done. $? was 0 in the first case which is plain wrong.

Comment: That sounds like the deployment succeeded, but later failed for an unrelated reason. From the perspective `kubectl` doing the deployment rollout, the pod passed its probes according to how it is configured, so it assumes the deployment was successful.

Comment: That’s plausible but painful. The pod was started and died within milliseconds. Any way to set a timer like minimumLifetimeBeforeSuccess or something?

Comment: The best way to mitigate that sort of scenario is the ensure your liveness and readiness probes are correctly set. From the sounds of it, the probes succeeded and the deployment therefore passed its update checks, but later failed.  Also check the logs of the offending pod during the update and see what error you are getting. Perhaps you are trying to mount a configmap or secret that doesn't exist or you are trying to connect to a service that is rejecting your connection request

Comment: The pod was never ready nor live. kubectl even reports “0 of 1 new replicas have been updated”. It knows the rollout failed why does it not return a failed code?

Comment: Can you share the yaml of your deployment. If the image is public, we can then use that to replicate your issue. It's not easy to see or understand what you're seeing without that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247368/discussion-between-blender-fox-and-marc).

Comment: It’s not reproducible. It happened once in hundreds of deployments.

Comment: > Any way to set a timer like minimumLifetimeBeforeSuccess or something? 
 https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#min-ready-seconds